# Add Filename as first line of file in shell script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files

Hello and thanks in advance.

I need to take a file, insert the filename as the first line of the file, then move to a different name.  Here's the wrinkle.  I need to grab the oldest file in the format of `ORIGFILE_YYYYMMDD.TXT` and save it as `NEWFILE.TXT`.  For this example, let's say the file name is `ORIGFILE_20151117.TXT`

1. Grab oldest file  (`ls -tr ORIGFILE*.txt`)
2. Add `ORIGFILE_20151117.TXT` as first line of file
3. Rename/Move  `ORIGFILE_20151117.TXT` to `NEWFILE.TXT`

Comment: Write the filename to `newfile.txt` and then append the entire contents of `origfile_20151117.txt`. After that delete the original file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's break this down into simple steps:

```
#!/bin/bash

# First, let's get that file's name:
FILE=$(ls -rt ORIGFILE*.txt | tail -n1)
if [[ 0 -ne $? ]]; then
    echo "Unable to locate matching file.  Aborting." 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

# Now, create a new file containing the file's name:
echo "$FILE" > NEWFILE.TXT

# And append the contents of the old file into the new:
cat "$FILE" >> NEWFILE.TXT

# Finally, get rid of the old file: (uncomment if you're sure)
# rm "$FILE"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
f=$(ls -1tr ORIGFILE*.txt | head -1); echo $f | cat - $f > NEWFILE.txt && rm $f
```

Comment: Only if the filenames don't contain nonprintable characters.